# pl/sql handling duplicate

Tags: sql, database, plsql

Hello i have to make procedure that insert new row and do rollback when other worker has the same  surname exists in table.

I checked in internet and here but can't find specific info. I must use exception dup_val_on_index

```
create or replace PROCEDURE insert_date(
   p_id IN WORKERS.ID%TYPE,
   p_PESEL IN WORKERS.PESEL%TYPE,
   p_name IN WORKERS.NAME%TYPE,
   p_surname IN WORKERS.SURNAME%TYPE,
   p_date_birth IN WORKERS.DATE_BIRTH%TYPE,
   p_salary IN WORKERS.SALARY%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO WORKERS VALUES (p_id, p_PESEL,p_name,p_surname, p_date_birth,p_salary);

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
   dbms_output.put_line('DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception.');
    ROLLBACK;
END;

BEGIN
insert_date(5,92060111111,'wikta','dss',TO_DATE('2003/07/10',    'yyyy/mm/dd'),100);
END;
```

Comment: Is your code not working for you -- if not, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check whether SURNAME already exist or not in the table. If not present then you can insert and commit the row. Try this :

```
create PROCEDURE insert_date(
p_id IN WORKERS.ID%TYPE,
p_PESEL IN WORKERS.PESEL%TYPE,
p_name IN WORKERS.NAME%TYPE,
p_surname IN WORKERS.SURNAME%TYPE,
p_date_birth IN WORKERS.DATE_BIRTH%TYPE,
p_salary IN WORKERS.SALARY%TYPE)

IS 
  varTmp NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
-- check here whether the surname already exist or not
SELECT decode((select max(t.d) from (SELECT 1 d FROM WORKERS WHERE SURNAME = p_surname) t),1, 2) INTO varTmp FROM dual;

-- insert
IF (varTmp <> 2) THEN
    INSERT INTO WORKERS VALUES (p_id, p_PESEL,p_name,p_surname, p_date_birth,p_salary);
 ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Row can not be inserted.');
END IF;
 COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
 when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
 dbms_output.put_line('DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception.');
  ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: What benefit is there in checking if the surname exists, since you're still handling the dup_val_on_index exception as well? Hint: the query may sometimes fail to detect a duplicate anyway

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code and there is nothing wrong with it, it works as expected (it falls to dup_val_on_index exception when executed twice)

The only thing which I can think of can be wrong is that you are not defining your primary key or unique key.
So your table definition should be e.g. like this

```
create table workers 
 (  id number,
    PESEL number,
    name varchar2(20),
    surname varchar2(20),
    date_birth date,
    salary number,
  CONSTRAINT worker_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

or alternatively you can add primary or unique key to an existing column

```
alter table workers
  add constraint PK_workers primary key (ID);
```